# Regex for validating passwith allowing specific special character

Tags: regex, validation, passwords

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern that will do the following:

- Require at least 1 uppercase character in any position
- Require at least 1 lowercase character in any position
- Require at least 1 digit in any position
- Allow (but not require) the special characters !$& in any position

Any help would be appreciated

Examples that should work:

- Passw0rd
- !Passw0rd1
- Pass!w20rd

Examples that should not work:

- !Passw@ord24
- password
- Passw@rd24
- Password

Comment: Is underscore also allowed?

Comment: hey fellow triangler - it be great if can you give an example of a password that would work and one that should fail.  Also any particular language you're working with?

Comment: Actually it's a dynamic field where the allowed special characters can be predefined, so yes it could be. I'm more looking for the correct way to write the pattern. I've actually got the first there, the required fields, those were fairly simply. I'm having difficulty getting the allowed characters to work without them being required.

Comment: @Anthony I added a few examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*\d)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9!&$]*[a-z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9!&$]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!&$]+$
```

You also can change `+` to range `{4,}` or `{4,50}` to prevent too small passwords or/and too large passwords.

Comment: Im accepting this answer as it seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks a bunch for everyones feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be something like (a bit naive, but should work, maybe there is more efficient way):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-0]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|
([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)
```

Of course it has to be adjusted to the language syntax regex according to the language you are using.
In Java:

```
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|"
        + "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|"
        + "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|"
        + "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-0]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|"
        + "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)|"
        + "([a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9!$&]*)";

    String[] passList = new String[] { "Passw0rd", "!Passw0rd1", "Pass!w20rd", "!Passw@ord24", "password",
        "Passw@rd24", "Password" };
    for (String pass : passList)
    {
        System.out.print(pass + ": " + pass.matches(regex)+", ");
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Passw0rd: true, !Passw0rd1: true, Pass!w20rd: true, !Passw@ord24: false, password: false, Passw@rd24: false, Password: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If more than one expression is allowey, can use something like (in `perl` syntax):

```
if ($pw =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9!\$&]/) {
    print "Usage of not allow characters.\n";
} else {
    if ($pw =~ /[a-z]/ && $pw =~ /[A-Z]/ && $pw =~ /\d/) {
        print "okay\n";
    } else {
        print "not okay\n";
    }       
}
```

Works with all examples above.